# Error pushing to new account repository in github

Tags: github

So, I switched a github repository from 1 account to another, and on the new account, removed the first account's permissions, but when trying to push, I get this error: `remote: Permission to (my project).git denied to first (account).` I already set the new account in git using `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email` but I still get the error

Comment: git doesnot care about user.name or user.email, in the second github account, do you have the SSH key added?

Comment: Small correction to @PaulBradbury's comment: Github does not care about these.

Comment: Correction to both of you: GitHub surely cares about `user.email` — it uses email to relate commits to GitHub accounts. But `user.name`/`user.email` are not pull/push credentials. Credentials for protocol `https://` are PATs, credentials for `ssh://` are SSH keypairs.